# How to compare files in two .zip folder in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I can compare files in two different folder with the commands:

```
$test = get-childitem -recurse -path C:\test 
$test1 = get-childitem -recurse -path C:\test1
$counter = (diff $test $test1).count
```

I would like to know how many differences between those two folders. This works.

However, now I would like to compare the filenames in two .zip files. Is it possible to compare the files inside two .zip files and I get a return value for the counter of different files?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You'll need to open the zip.  If you have dotnet 4.5 it's got support for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tested .NET ZIP functionality on PowerShell V4. I suspect it would work on V3 but not on V2 (or V1).

```
Add-Type -AN System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$zip1 = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead("c:\test\test1.zip")
$zip2 = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead("c:\test\test2.zip")
$names1 = $zip1.Entries.FullName
$names2 = $zip2.Entries.FullName
$counter = (diff $names1 $names2).count
$zip1.Dispose()
$zip2.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, unfortunately, I am using V1. I am not sure I can change the version since it is sharing by many ppl. Is there any way to deal with it under V1?

Comment: Wow V1 is 7 years old.  Even V2 is getting long in the tooth.  :-)  In this case, I think you're going to need to get a snapin like PSCX (http://pscx.codeplex.com/releases/view/1615).  It has a read-archive command that read the contents of a ZIP file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. I tested in my V3. Well, it gives me some errors when I tried

Comment: the errors are listed as: add-type : cannot add type. The assembly 'system.io.compress.filesystem' could not be found.

Comment: This is wonderfully elegant and can even be used to check if the **content is the same** if we replace `Entries.FullName` with `Entries.Crc32` (Please note that this is not perfect as it could lead to false negatives when checksums accidentally match up even though contents are different.)